# Boot problem after installing Ubuntu 13.10 Operating System Not Found VAIO

Tags: boot, system-installation, vaio

I have a Sony VAIO bought in 2013 (model SVS151290X). First I wanted to run Windows 8 + Ubuntu so I deleted the WIndows Recovery partition(32gb) and tried to install the Ubuntu there. Something wrong happened during the attempt to install that I didn't even go trough the installation process and when I restarted the computer, it wouldn't boot but show a message:

"Operating System Not Found"

I knew Windows files would still be there, but neither Sony nor Microsoft would give me any recovery media. (Vaio don't come with a CD or USB with Windows 8 and they say the product key is inside the BIOS).

I decided then, something I should have done long time ago, to install only Ubuntu. I made a new USB with the Ubuntu 13.10 and selected the option to erase disk and install Ubuntu. Everything went fine in the installation but when it finished, it asked to reboot. After rebooting the same error message appeared:

"Operating System Not Found"

I have tried many things for days but still can't find the reason why it is happening.
Here is the log file for the boot repair: paste.ubuntu.com/7221785

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Boot Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). It should repair your Ubuntu installation.

For instructions on downloading and using it, please refer to [this excellent guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I've cleaned up your answer to improve the formatting and content. In the future, please craft your answers so that they meet our [quality standards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-answer). Thank you for your first answer, and  welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community! :)

Comment: I have already tried that. Here is the log file:
paste.ubuntu.com/7221785